# MySQL syntax error - near '' at line 1 php

Tags: php, mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

That what I getting error right now. I searched in internet and  I can not seem to find it. Others said it's '' in variable ('$order_id') but it didn't solve the error.

When I click Accept button which is submitAccept then it will pop up a message "Order Accepted" BUT instead of that it pops up the aformentioned error. How do I fix this?

Here my sql code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitDelivered'])){  
  $order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['t_order_id']));
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Delivered' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  if (mysqli_query(connection2(), $query)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "COMMIT");
         $_SESSION['message'] = "Order Delivered"; } 
         else { 
         $_SESSION['message'] = mysqli_error(connection2());
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "ROLLBACK");
         }
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submitAccept'])){  
  $order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['t_order_id']));
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Accepted' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  if (mysqli_query(connection2(), $query)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "COMMIT");
         $_SESSION['message'] = "Order Accepted"; } 
         else { 
         $_SESSION['message'] = mysqli_error(connection2());
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "ROLLBACK");
         }
  }      

  if(isset($_POST['submitCancel'])){  
  $order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['t_order_id']));
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Cancelled' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  if (mysqli_query(connection2(), $query)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "COMMIT");
         $_SESSION['message'] = "Order Cancelled"; } 
         else { 
         $_SESSION['message'] = mysqli_error(connection2());
         mysqli_query(connection2(), "ROLLBACK");
         }
  }      
  ?>
```

Comment: Everytime someone runs a PHP query without prepared statements, a fuzzy kitten dies somewhere.  Use prepared statements, which would likely already solve the problem you are having.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @timbiegeleisen How can I do that bro? Im not good in query :(

Comment: @johnconde Yeah bro after I solve this problem that what Im gonna do.

Comment: Just Google around for this, you will certainly find some good tutorials out there.

Comment: At least do us the favor of narrowing down the problem to a single statement.

Comment: Don't just dump here 40 lines of code if only 3 of them are necessary. E.g., what does your question have to do with $_SESSION? Nothing. Read about how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Timbiegeleisen I spent a couple of hrs searching for the answer bro. I wont be here bro if I find the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It didn't show the message "Accepted" bro.

Comment: Are you trying to use transactions? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php You also can simplify this. Use a single query, and make the value being updated a variable.

Comment: @Al.G. Sorry bro, Im new here and I just want to show the whole code just to be sure and clear.

Comment: Which query is even giving you a headache? Remove everything else apart from that query

Comment: @rndus2r All 3 button bro, in line $query ...  etc

Comment: @Dragon12 Don't bro me if you don't know me :-)

Comment: @TimBiegelsen your stash of fuzzy kittens must be getting severely depleted

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I didn't mean that. Its just im stress and so much to work with. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that MySQL error is derived from the PHP you display in the question? **What was the value of $order_id when you got that error?**

```
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Delivered' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Accepted' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Cancelled' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
```

There is no obvious SQL syntax error in any of the 3 queries shown UNLESS something bad has been put into $order_id.

Please note I am not commenting on your PHP as I'm not expert is that, but I do know you should be using prepared statements (and many have advised already).